# 9D (Hex) character remove in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

i want select family from my_table where family LIKE '%HEX(9D)'
family hex format ended with 9D hex
i convert excel file in to sqlite database but
some of my data add 9D in ended
i can not search correctly
please guide me
how can remove 9D hex character in family column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get HEX(9D) in SQLLite use `cast(X'9D' as text)`. So to update use something like:

`UPDATE YOURTABLE SET YOURCOLUMN=REPLACE(YOURCOLUMN,cast(X'9D' as text),'') where YOURCOLUMN like '%'||cast(X'9D' as text)||'%'`;

or just

```
UPDATE YOURTABLE SET YOURCOLUMN=REPLACE(YOURCOLUMN,X'9D','') where YOURCOLUMN like '%'||x'9D'||'%';
```

Comment: when i run this script show this error SQL Error: near "'9D'": syntax error

Comment: that is oh thanks . there is a problem when i use like '%'||x'9D'||'%'; not retrieval all records,it return one record  why?

Comment: what happen when i use only this code?--> UPDATE YOURTABLE SET YOURCOLUMN=REPLACE(YOURCOLUMN,X'9D','')

Comment: It has the same effect. If YOURCOLUMN doesn't contain x'9d' REPLACE returns YOURCOLUMN so YOURCOLUMN won't be changed.