# Remove UTF-8 substring in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, utf-8

I am trying to remove [some invisible characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/202b/index.htm) from a table. I tried this query:

```
UPDATE table SET text = REPLACE(text, x'202B', '' )
```

with no luck. I also tried selecting it using:

```
SELECT REPLACE(text, x'202B', '@@@@') AS text FROM table
```

but nothing is replaced, so I'm guessing that it can't find `x'202B'` in the `text` column, but if I use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text REGEXP "[\x202B]"
```

I do get results.

Comment: Not quite marking as a duplicate, because I haven't tested it, but have you cast your UTF-8 value to `text`, as in the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958528/9d-hex-character-remove-in-sqlite

Comment: Use the `CHAR` function to construct strings from Unicode scalar values, see https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x'202B'` is not a single, invisible Unicode character; it is a blob containing the two ASCII characters  and `+`.

All SQLite strings are encoded in UTF-8.
When you are constructing strings from bytes manually, you have to use the same encoding:

```
x'E280AB'
```

Comment: Any idea how to make this work in MySql? It's erroneously returning all the rows.

Comment: This question is not about MySQL. To ask a new question, use the "Ask Question" button.