# Remove hex character from Postgres data

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a Postgres database `bg` that uses WIN1252 encoding. To get around UTF8 conversion issues, I want to remove values like 0x9D from my data. How would I remove these values from a column named `comments` in `bg.bg."DEV"`?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958528/9d-hex-character-remove-in-sqlite), I've tried:

```
UPDATE bg.bg."DEV"
SET "comments" = REPLACE(comments, X'9D','') 
WHERE "comments" like '%'||x'9D'||'%';
```

However this throws:

```
ERROR:  "%" is not a valid binary digit
LINE 3: WHERE "comments" like '%'||x'9D'||'%';
                              ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I was able to use the following:

```
UPDATE tablename SET field=replace(field, chr(x'9D'::int), '')
WHERE strpos(field,chr(x'9D'::int))>0;
```

As per this question on [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/194857/remove-characters-from-postgresql-database-causing-encoding-errors)

Comment: Very helpful...  I was so close.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to match 0x9D in the comments column. 
The where clause should be

```
WHERE "comments" like '%0x9D%'
```

Comment: I don't want to match the string '0x9D'; I'm looking to match a hex value.

Comment: if the comments field is a varchar(string), all the content can be searched as string. Can you please post a sample string from your comment which has this hex value